# What to use for image gallery using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to display images retrieving through parse in an imageview. I want to keep the images swipe-able both left and right. I am confused in what method to use. Could anyone please guide me for what might be right for me keeping in mind things i want to achieve.  Any example or tutorial would certainly help.

Thank-you.

Comment: If you tell us what you already know/have and what particular point stops you from going on it is much easier to answer your question. else it is likely that the question will be closed as beeing to broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a specific class like `Gallery1` that holds all the image and image name.

If `Gallery1` is class & `image` is a column name (i.e key in `parse`), You can get the ImageUrl by,

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Gallery1");
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");

    try {
        parseObjects = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : ", e.getMessage());
    }

    for (ParseObject parseObject : parseObjects) {

        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("image");
        if (image!=null) {

            Log.d("image", image.getUrl());
        }
      }
```

For Swiping left and right, there are too many SO posts available here. Here are few

[Best way to swipe images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012363/best-way-to-swipe-images-in-android?rq=1)

[How can i swipe the images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665144/how-can-i-swipe-the-images-in-android?rq=1https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665144/how-can-i-swipe-the-images-in-android?rq=1)

[Image viewpager swiping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840675/image-viewpager-swiping?rq=1)

Good luck :)